# Update dictionary value regardless of key's location

Tags: python

Is there a function in Python that could change the value of a key regardless of key's location? For example, the `data` has no nested `map` while the `model` has. The value of `data['longitude']` should be placed in `model['map']['longitude']`. I don't have any idea how can I do this, is it possible?

```
data = {
    'record': 'Nicaragua',
    'text': 'Hello World!',
    'latitude': 10.1,
    'longitude': 122.55,
    'address': None
}

model = {
    "_id": 1535083840,
    "record": "Germany",
    "text": "<br>",
    "map": {
        "latitude": 0.0,
        "longitude": 0.0
    }
}


model.pop("_id")  # removing the _id in model

expected_result = {
    "record": "Nicaragua",
    "text": "Hello World!",
    "map": {
        "latitude": 10.1,
        "longitude": 122.55
    }
}
```

Comment: `model['map']['longitude'] = data['longitude']` ?

Comment: So only latitude and longitude should be moved to the map of model?

Comment: To replace the value without knowing the `latitude` position within the model. It's like `some_builtin_function(model, "latitude", data['latitude'])` then the output should be the same as `model['map']['longitude'] = data['longitude']`. I have different model with dynamic key-value pair, knowing the location individually could be a mess.

Comment: You could scan all dictionaries in your workspace and then go through all the keys that match yours, but I wouldn't recommend that.
Why don't you build a unique dictionary with nested attributes for each key? That would be a cleaner and simple solution. Otherwise, first comment looks like what you are looking for.

Comment: @E.Serra This is my design of storing documents to MongoDB.

Comment: You could still do doc = {'data': data, 'model': model} or even better store them in an object and make the common keys point to the same attribute in the object (So you only have to change them In one place and gets populated everywhere).

Comment: You don't need to know the location in the dictionary. As long as your key has a specific value then accessing it shouldn't be a problem. Also you could create a function that takes model, "latitude", data['latitude']) as argument and update the dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
data = {
    'record': 'Nicaragua',
    'text': 'Hello World!',
    'latitude': 10.1,
    'longitude': 122.55,
    'address': None
}

model = {
    "record": "Germany",
    "text": "<br>",
    "map": {
        "latitude": 0.0,
        "longitude": 0.0
    }
}


def r_update(target, key, value):
    if key in target:
        target[key] = value
    else:
        for k, v in target.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                r_update(v, key, value)


def update(source, target):
    for key, value in source.items():
        r_update(target, key, value)


update(data, model)
print(model)
```

**Output**

```
{'record': 'Nicaragua', 'text': 'Hello World!', 'map': {'longitude': 122.55, 'latitude': 10.1}}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but I just want to replace the value without calling the model's latitude position. It's like `some_builtin_function(model, "latitude", data['latitude'])` then the output should be the same as `model['map']['longitude'] = data['longitude']`.

Comment: But why your expected output has 'record': Nicaragua?

Comment: The data will override the values within the model having the same key name regardless of its position. The model with Germany as `record` should also be replaced by Nicaragua. Again, it's like `some_builtin_function(model, "record", data['record'])` then the output should be the same as `model['record'] = data['record']` or `model.update('record', data['record']`).

Comment: Updated the answer